# Laravel Eloquent retrieve row with JSON column

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent

I have following data in my table

### Table:

```
id    |name   | option_data

1     |Joe    |{"gender":"Male","cnic":"1234567","dob":"2016-03-14"}     
2     |Doe    |{"gender":"Male","cnic":"9999","dob":"2016-03-14"}
```

How can I get data in proper json_encode format.

For example if I write

```
echo json_encode($app->auth->users);
```

### My Output for option_data

```
option_data":"{\"gender\":\"Male\",\"cnic\":\"61101-6859110-3\",\"dob\":\"2016-03-14\"}"
```

My database column type is `Text`. If I remove all `\` using stripslashes still data is not a valid JSON because its wrapped in  `"` double qoutes.

### Question

How can I get data in proper json_encode format with all other coulmns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with accesor in your model, to your data model

```
public function getOptionDataAttribute($value)
{
    return json_decode($value);
}
```

and return in your controller:

```
return Model::all(); //What you need to retrieve
```

the output must be:

```
{
    id: 1
    name: name,
    option_data: {"gender":"Male","cnic":"1234567","dob":"2016-03-14"}
}
```

Comment: getting  undefined function response(). My actual code is little bit complex which is using hasMany method.

Comment: that code should work, you put the accesor in your model Application and return in your controller $applicants right? it's working in my project @Nomi

Comment: sorry I just removed my comments. I had less knowledge about accesor. Now I have studied and tested it. I am facing one issue here. If I use  `getnameAttribute` and try to modify it works fine but I column's name has underscores for example in  `getOption_dataAttribute` its not working and show undefined method error.  Actually its looking for  `getOptiondataAttribute` Should I rename my column names or there is right way to do it?

Comment: @Nomi set the accesor as `getOptionDataAttribute`, I just edited my answer

Comment: thanks for help. I have  changed options_data to optiondata in database column with that its working. One more thing I have also used ```echo $app->auth->users__tostring()```.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112184/discussion-between-jose-rojas-and-nomi).

Answer (score 16):

You can just use $casts variable in your model and it will automatically convert to json and reverse to array.

```
protected $casts = [
     "option_data" => "array"
];
```

Comment: Seems more laravel way of doing casts.